# Javascript getElementById from php foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript, loops, foreach, getelementbyid

So I have a php foreach loop as follows,

```
$i = 1;
foreach($rows as $record){
       <div id='ytplayer".$i++."'>
       </div>");
}
```

and then I have javascript which uses the `getElementById` and it needs to get the div everytime it is looped, which would essentially be an array, but how would I do that, I know what I have below wont work, but something like this, since I know this is pretty close to how you would get this to work in php

```
document.getElementById('ytplayer[i]');
```

Comment: I hope you know that PHP is executed on the server and JavaScript in the browser, on the client. With that in mind, I don't really understand your question. When/how/where is the JavaScript executed? Please add some more detail.

Comment: Yes I know that, but what I wanted is for javascript to getElemendById for all the divs that have id ytplayer, because there will be multiple of them ytplayer1, ytplayer2, ytplayer3 etc etc

Comment: It'd also be helpful if you gave us the HTML generated by the PHP script.  Most likely it will be `<div id="ytplayer1"></div>, <div id="ytplayer2"></div>, etc.` -- but still post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!

http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/5yUAx/

Assuming that your PHP writes the following divs(one,two etc are added for example sake...)

```
<div id='ytplayer1'>one</div>
<div id='ytplayer2'>two</div>
<div id='ytplayer3'>three</div>
<div id='ytplayer4'>four</div>

for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
var x=document.getElementById('ytplayer'+i);
  alert(x.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code with some explanation to your answer as well. Links can rot and then your answer won't be of any use.

Comment: sorry mate, I was in the middle of writing and accidentally clicked on save :)

Comment: @Chris: That's what DRTauli was suggesting as well (basically). What was the problem?

Comment: I needed the correct way of setting up the `for(var i=1; i<5; i++){` the other way i had it figured had it done a different way

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('ytplayer'+i);
```

Comment: @Chris: Then you probably have to provide more information. Where/how/when are you trying to call `document.getElementById('ytplayer[i]');`? We can only work with what you give us. Seriously, it is not clear what the relation of the JavaScript code is to the PHP code you posted (apart from that you want to access the elements that are generated by it, but the generated HTML would even be more relevant in this case).

Comment: @Chris This will work and is the proper way of doing it assuming you generate the correct <divs> as stated in Eswar Rajesh Pinapala answer.